# Why does the IHttpAsyncHandler provide extraData parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous

*A bit not relevant for today's technology but I [saw another way of working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rNNJ.png) with Tasks in   APM environment , besides the `Task.FromAsync`*

Async Handler in asp.net :

```
public class Handler : IHttpAsyncHandler
{

 public IAsyncResult BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, object extraData)
    {
      //...
    }

    public void EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
    {
     //...
    }
  }
```

- The `context` parameter is the actual context which I can access`/`(or pass to another beginXXX operation) request and response.
- `cb` is for me to execute`/`(or pass to another beginXXX operation) when the operation finished.

**Question**

But what is the `object extraData` is doing in the signature of the method ?

It is *not* that I get some state from the framework , on the contrary - I *create* state and pass it forward so that my EndXXX could cast `result.AsyncState` to  T and use that data.

So why is it there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, it is required by the [APM Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which `IHttpAsyncHandler` is following. You don't need it here, but there are cases (of pattern usage, not handler usage) when it is useful to correlate callbacks.

**Update:**

Here's the [recommended way](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997423%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to use `Task`s in  APM:

```
public IAsyncResult BeginCalculate(int decimalPlaces, AsyncCallback ac, object state)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Calling BeginCalculate on thread {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    Task<string> f = Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(_ => Compute(decimalPlaces), state);
    if (ac != null) f.ContinueWith((res) => ac(f));
    return f;
}

public string Compute(int numPlaces)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Calling compute on thread {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

    // Simulating some heavy work.
    Thread.SpinWait(500000000);

    // Actual implemenation left as exercise for the reader.
    // Several examples are available on the Web.
    return "3.14159265358979323846264338327950288";
}

public string EndCalculate(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Calling EndCalculate on thread {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    return ((Task<string>)ar).Result;
}
```

Please note that the state is passes to task factory, and the resulted task is used as both the argument to the callback and the return value.

Comment: Yeah  , I thought so / just wanted to be sure. It just want to be a good APM citizen . Hence it follows the protocol. But it actually does _nothing_

Comment: Still, don't forget to pass it to `IAsyncResult.AsyncState`.

Comment: I guess you meant to say "when you dont have any state" - but if I do - then   [I already doing it via the TCS](http://i.imgur.com/2LHERrg.png)

Comment: No, I mean "always". You are expected to set `AsyncState` to the value of last parameter of `BeginXXX`.